# Xpath - Selecting self or closest previous non-empty element

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following document:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td>390920000</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>390920000</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3924100011</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3924100011</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3924100019</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3924100019</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I would like is to use an xpath to select /html/body/div/table/tr/td[2], but for each empty element select the previous non-empty element instead. So instead of getting the values 'A','','B','','','C' I would like to get 'A','A','B','B','B','C'. Is this possible?

Btw, nevermind that this is an html and not an xml. I am using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) so I create ordinary xpath expressions to select html elements.

Comment: Do you want 'A','B','C' or 'A','A','B','B','B','C'??

Comment: I want 'A','A','B','B','B','C'. This has now been solved by selecting all and processing the result at a later stage. Still curious whether or not it would have been possible to do this directly using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

If XPath 3 is fine, the following should work:

```
//table/tr ! head((., reverse(preceding-sibling::*))[normalize-space(td[2]/text()) != ""])/td[2]
```